# Papyrus palette customization

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, activity-diagram, papyrus

I'm using Papyrus MDT with Eclipse Kepler. I need to customize the palette in order to include activity diagram elements (`CallOperationAction`) into a sequence diagram. I read Papyrus palette customization tutorial but I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

- Right click on the palette
- `Customize...`
- In the left panel (`Available palettes`) choose groups you need

But notice, diagrams from ALL elements are turned on by default. Rather you need turn them off.